# Trying to create an overlay on my web page by a chrome extension. But the html overlay does not show

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open an overlay element in the current page I am in. To do this with Google Chrome extensions, I am sending a message from the background.js to the content.js. And I am trying to load the html whcih holds the overlay in content.js. My guess is, my html only creates the overlay but does not show it. Is this the case?

Here are my codes:
content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        
        if (request.greeting == "xx"){
            
            var iframe  = document.createElement ('iframe');
            iframe.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ('xx.html');
            document.body.appendChild (iframe);
        
        }
      
    }
    
  );
```

And xx.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>


</body>
</html>
```

And additionally, the html is added to my manifest file as web accesible resource:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],"web_accessible_resources": [
        "xx.html"
        
      ],
```

Comment: You literally set display: none on you overlay class div.  Besides that, your html is added to the page, but it is below page content. Set the z-index to something high, like 99999